# Access the list of items send from view model to serialised

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a dango app where I try to add all answer alternative to a question (from db) in the serializer. Which seems to work.

```
**My Model**

class MyModel(models.Model):
    Question = models.TextField(null=False, blank= False)
    Answer=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False,blank= False)

    def __str__(self):
        return Question

**My View Model**

class get_english_q(APIView):
    serializer = English_Q_Serializer

    def get(self,request,**kwargs):
        language = self.kwargs.get('id')
        list1 = MyModel.objects.filter(.....)
        list2 = MyModel.objects.filter(.....)
        list3 = MyModel.objects.filter(.....)
        array1 = random.sample([x.id for x in list1], k=5)
        array2 = random.sample([x.id for x in list2], k=5)
        array3 = random.sample([x.id for x in list3], k=5)
        array1.extend(array2)
        array1.extend(array3)
        list = MyModel.objects.filter(id__in=array1)
        serializer = English_Q_Serializer(list, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


**My Serializer Model**

class English_Q_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answers = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_words')

    class Meta:
        model = english_technical
        fields = (
            'answers',
            'id',
            'question',
        )

    def get_words(self, instance):
        list_all=MyModel.objects.all()
        answers=[instance.answer]
        array = random.sample([x.answer for x in list if x.answer != instance.answer],k=4)
        answers.extends(array)
        return answers
```

Now when I define the list of questions to include I take 5 from one queryset, 5 from another and 5 from another. Now I want to make logic in serializer different depending on if they were in first set of 5, second set of 5 or third set of 5.

Is there a way that I in the serializer can get the index of an item in the list that is sent from the view model. I.e. that if an instance is one of the first five in the list do this....:

I hope I'm able to explain what I try to do.

Answer (score 1):

How about using context to pass additional information to the serializer from the view.
So create a mapping of question id set to number (1, 2 or 3 etc)

```
question_set_mapping = {qid: i // 5 + 1 for i, qid in enumerate(array1)}
```

Then in the serializer access the context.

```
question_set_mapping = self.context.get('question_set_mapping', {})
```

Modify get_words method based on the set number:

```
set_number = question_set_mapping.get(instance.id)

    # Now you can use the set_number to modify the behavior
    if set_number == 1:
        # Do something for questions in the first set
    elif set_number == 2:
        # Do something for questions in the second set
```

Hope that makes sense and good luck :)

Comment: Just what I did. Sometimes you don't think clear. Thanks for your contribution. Works like a charm.